# Why changes made to a node module does not apply to React.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, leaflet, google-chrome-devtools

I installed node modules with

```
npm install
```

After that I changed few lines in one of the modules. The lines in red rectangle are where the changes has been made.

[image]

Notice that `find` command line tool detects only one file with that name.

Then started my react app:

```
npm run start
```

Opening the Chrome's DevTools I expected to see those changes in the modified file, but instead the file was not affecte by any change. I mean the file looks the same way like how it initially used to be.

[image]

I cleared all browser's cache, deleted node_modules/.cache

```
rm -fr node_modules/.cache
```

I restarted the browser, even my PC. The name of the library which source I try to change is `leaflet`. I have installed another modules that 'peer-depend' on that library. There are no global npm installations of `leaflet` on my PC:

```
>:~/Coding/test/react-leaflet-marker$ npm list -g --depth=0
/home/cloud-of-sounds/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib
├── @storybook/cli@5.2.6
├── cordova@8.1.1
├── http-server@0.11.1
├── json-minify@1.0.0
├── minify@4.1.3
├── npm@6.4.1
├── phonegap@8.2.2
└── plugman@3.0.1
```

I can't get my head around that problem. Can you help me how to make my browser load these changes?

Comment: Does your `npm run start` rebuild the app too?

Comment: I'm not sure. How to check that? That's what I have in my `package.json: `  "scripts": {  "start": "react-scripts start" }

Comment: Not sure if react-scripts rebuilds when you run start. You can change the node module file, then run `react-scripts build`, _then_ run `react-scripts start` see if it's updated then

Comment: You're not changing the right file (`leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js` vs `leaflet/src/layer/marker/Icon.Default.js`), and you are being fooled about which files are being loaded because of sourcemaps. Leaflet does not rebuild when you expect.

Comment: Thank you, @IvanSanchez! After I cloned `leaflet` project from github I made those changes again in `leaflet/src/layer/marker/Icon.Default.js`. Next I run `npm install` and `npm run rollup` and voila! Chrome debuger now display correctly the code's modification.

Comment: Thanks to one of the main contributors to leaflet - @IvanSanchez I figured out how to solve my problem. Please find the solution in a separate answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @IvanSanchez! I replaced the folder in `node_modules` with the latest `leaflet` I cloned from github. I made those changes in `leaflet/src/layer/marker/Icon.Default.js` again. Next I run

```
npm install
```

and

```
npm run rollup
```

and voila! Chrome debuger now displays correctly the code's modifications.

CONCLUSION: In a npm package `src/` folder contains development's stage code rather than `dist/` which contains production's stage code! It looks like that running `npm run rollup` builds the code in `src/` and outputs it in `dist/`.

Comment: It looks like rollup isn't a standard npm script, could you confirm which package it's from?

Comment: This script particulary is a part of `leaflet` node module.  Check inside  `leaflet` `package.json`: file "scripts": {
    ...
    "rollup": "rollup -c build/rollup-config.js",
    ...
}